# Oracle Apex IG Query to compare columns between tables across databases

Tags: sql, dynamic, oracle-apex

I have an IG Grid query:

```
select db_name, db_position, db_enabled, db_access from db_all where db_name = decode(:P1_DATABASE_NAME, 'All',database_name, :P1_DATABASE_NAME);--decode part because of the select list for databases
```

I need to add a column in this query that either displays change in colour/yes or no and is a link.

The column should be the comparison between db_all table and db_all table in the database mentioned in db_name column.

The databases are multiple, hence query needs to be dynamic and comparison has to be column by column, ie of all 4 tables between the local table and the database in the db_name.

There's another table which has db links:

```
select db_link, db_name from db_link_details;
```

This can be joined with db_all table if needed on basis of db_name

However I am unsure how dynamically this can be done.

I have created a function as well to dynamically pull db_links but not sure how this can be modified/fitted here. It's purpose was to pull count of the rows in the target database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_LINK_CNT
(LINK IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS ROW_CNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB_ALL@'||LINK INTO ROW_CNT;
RETURN ROW_CNT
END;
```